# Good source for current taxonomic keys

Tags: entomology, taxonomy

I’ve recently taken back up my interest in entomology and taxonomy. I used to be a biologist, but have long since moved to another field to make my way. I realize that all of my taxonomic keys are likely way out of date as they are mainly from the 1970s and earlier. So I’m looking for keys mainly dealing with the order Neuroptera in insects. Does anyone know where you can obtain current info?

Comment: There's the [International Committee on Zoological Nomenclature](https://www.iczn.org/), which has ZooBank, a collection of publications on nomenclature etc.  Keys would strongly depend on where you are in the world. Have you checked out the external links on Wikipedia for Neuroptera? Looks like some candidates there.

Comment: Thanks bob1, those two leads are what I needed.